# Product demo using Canvas Animation

Tags: html

I love the way Sublime text shows it's product demo on it's home page: http://www.sublimetext.com/

How can I create a similar demo? All I note is that it is a Canvas element.

Kindly recommend an easy way to do this - using an API or a software tool.

Sorry if it's sounds as a basic question. I see it's made on Canvas. Any leads or help in this regard is highly appreciated.